# No Audio - Ubuntu 20.04 - NVIDIA - Dell XPS 17

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, dell

After installing Ubuntu on my Dell XPS 17, I have no sound coming out. If I check the settings, the sound output is "dummy output".

If I run the lspci -vnn | grep -iA4 audio instruction, here is the result :

```
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43c8] (rev 11)
Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0a5d]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 205
Memory at 628d1d8000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Memory at 628d000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
--
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:228e] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0a5d]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
Memory at aa000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
```

Does anyone know how I could solve this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

Edit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

`sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

Search for "options snd-hda-intel model". If it exists, modify the line to look like the following. If it doesn't exist, just add the following to the bottom of the file. Reboot. Retest audio.

```
# Enable internal audio and headphone jack on Dell
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Now I have a sound :)
Still one problem, only the right speaker work..

Comment: @Florent Check the BALANCE setting in the Sound Settings panel. See what happens if you plug in external speakers or a headphone. Do both speakers work under Windows?

Comment: I tried yesterday on WIndows and I sounded like it was the same issue. Today I have my both speakers working.. Maybe I was the video the problem..